# CS0030: Cannot convert type 'int' to 'bool'

Tags: c#, int, boolean

where is the problem with my code??
i can't compile it on microsoft visual studio 2015
anyone can help? what should i change and where is the problem?

```
private void SelectAll_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
  GridColumn column = (GridColumn) e.Item.Tag;
  int dataRowCount = this.gridViewCastles.DataRowCount;
  bool flag1 = true;
  bool flag2 = true;
  this.gridViewCastles.BeginUpdate();
  try
  {
    for (int rowHandle = dataRowCount - 1; rowHandle >= 0; --rowHandle)
    {
      if (flag1)
      {
        flag2 = !(bool) this.gridViewCastles.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, column);
        flag1 = false;
      }
      this.gridViewCastles.SetRowCellValue(rowHandle, column, (object) (bool) (flag2 ? 1 : 0));
    }
  }
  finally
  {
    this.gridViewCastles.EndUpdate();
  }
}
```

Comment: Tag the language, not useless typenames/verbs. Explain what you're trying to do. Provide a minimal example that others can test. "i can't compile it" => Quote the error(s) that are stopping you. Would that be so difficult?

Comment: Please, next time give more information so people can easily understand the problem. For example, you could say that you have a form with a certain type o0f control and you are trying to handle the click event to do something (explain what you want to do). Then explain what have you tried before asking and what results you have got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.gridViewCastles.SetRowCellValue(rowHandle, column, (object) (bool) (flag2 ? 1 : 0));
```

What are you trying to do?

Flag2 is a boolean. The ?: operator allows you to test a boolean condition to select one of two possible vaules, in your case, 0 and 1. In your code, you try to cast 0/1 to boolean. What is the reason for using the ?: operator? Just type this:

```
this.gridViewCastles.SetRowCellValue(rowHandle, column, (object) flag2);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here: `(bool) (flag2 ? 1 : 0)`. You're trying to convert an integer to a boolean using an explicit cast.

Use `Convert.ToBoolean` instead: `Convert.ToBoolean(flag2 ? 1 : 0)`. BTW, it seems like it's so useless: why do you want to convert `1` to `true` and `0` to `false` if `flag2` is already `bool`?

BTW, now you should have already realized that `bool` has no implicit or explicit conversion to `int` and vice versa and you need to use `Convert.ToBoolean`/`Convert.ToInt32`...

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
this.gridViewCastles.SetRowCellValue(rowHandle, column, (object)(flag2);
```

By:

```
this.gridViewCastles.SetRowCellValue(rowHandle, column, (object)(bool)(flag2 ? 1 : 0));
```

Comment: that worked! thank you very much!